# JPA Hibernate Specification

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am having following sql that needs to be transitioned to JPA specs:

```
select 
* from  TableA a
    cross join TableB b
    cross join (
        select distinct refAId from TableC c where c.name like 'Your_NAME'
        ) as T
where
T.refAId = a.id
```

How can I form the cross join T to the root TableA here in terms of entities?
So basically in the specification implementation I get CriteriaBuilder as Root root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb. Now how should i proceed ahead to map the root to the Query defined table T mentioned above?

Above query very efficient than the following:

```
select 
* from  TableA a
    cross join TableB b
where
a.id in (
select refAId from TableC c where c.name like 'Your_NAME'
)
```

Why it is more efficient because the scan c.name like 'Your_NAME' happenes only once in the first query.

Comment: Root here is Root<TableA> here

Answer (score 0):

The query can be rewritten in the following way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA a, TableB b, TableC c
WHERE c.name LIKE 'Your_NAME' 
AND c.refAId = a.id
```

The Criteria query then becomes:

```
var tableA = cq.from(TableA.class);
var tableB = cq.from(TableB.class);
var tableC = cq.from(TableC.class);
cq.where(cb.and(
    cb.equal(tableA_.id, tableC_.refAId), 
    cb.equal(tableC_.name, "YOUR_NAME")
));
cq.multiselect(...);
```

Is there no association between `TableA` and `TableC` entities, though? If there was one, you could simply do:

```
var tableC = cq.from(TableC.class);
var tableB = cq.from(TableB.class);
var tableA = tableC.join(TableC_.refA);
...
```

Comment: Yes. It is correct to mention in this way. But what is happening is that there is very huge dataset and i do not want everytime in the where clause scan results for c.name LIKE 'Your_NAME' . Instead if it could handle in the way that I originally mentioned then it improves the performance. So i do not want the conditions as a predicate in main where clause but in the cross join table itself

Comment: I have edited the question as I need this from performance point of view when there are trillions of combinations to be scanned. Thanks.